# Creating index with unique constraint for new blank field

Tags: constraints, hana, unique-constraint

A new column was added to an existing DB table (`PA0023`).

DB: HANA

The column should be unique, therefore i tried to create a unique index constraint via `SE11`.

[image: SE11]

Activation succeeded. However, while creating the index via `Utilities... Database Utility`, an error showed up:

> Request: Create Index PA0023-Z01
>
> ...
>
> sql:
>
> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 'PA0023~Z01' ON 'PA0023'
>   ('MANDT',
>    'RECORD_KEY')
> ```
>
> cannot CREATE UNIQUE INDEX; duplicate key found [5] Several documents with the same ID exist in the index;SAPABAP1:PA0023.$uc_PA0023~Z01$ content not unique, cannot define unique constraint. rowCount != distinctCount.

There aren't rows with the same value filled in that column. There are rows with blank value, which are considered duplicates. After replacing blanks in development environment, index was created well. It's less possible in production, because there are many records with an empty value in that new field.

So my question is: Is there a way to create the unique constraint without replacing the blanks?

Comment: I don't see a solution other than adding another column to make the index really unique. Is it a problem for you? (try to choose one column as small as possible to have the smallest index possible)

Comment: Hey @SandraRossi. The target is to make `RECORD_KEY` alone to a unique column.

Comment: Why focusing on making it unique absolutely? I find it a harsh idea to enforce a rule in a system which is not under your responsibility and control. Better define the key "not unique". I don't think that a non-unique index slows the processing significantly compared to a unique index.

Comment: Hey @SandraRossi. this column represents the identity of the record. we want to set the constraint in the lowest level, which is DB level.

Comment: @Dorad - if it is the record identity, then surely it should be unique to tell the records apart ...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a unique constraint if the existing data does not provide uniqueness.  So no you  can't do this if you have multiple NULL values for the key.  You would need to ensure the data is unique before creating the constraint.

This is normal database practice, it's not HANA specific.

Comment: As an exception, IBM DB2 "logical files" can define both a selection criteria and a key.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that a compound primary key cannot contain any nullable columns it is permitted for a compound unique/candidate key to be defined with nullable columns. The only golden rule is that when adding or updating a record if any column in the unique key contains a NULL value then the index entry is *NOT* written to the database.

MySQL does this by default.
SQL Server will do this provided that you add "WHERE columnX IS NOT NULL" to the key's definition.
ORACLE is the same as SQL Server, except that the syntax is more complicated.